# Автозагрузка приложения

Tags: java, postgresql

Доброго всем времени суток! Есть такая задача: нужно, чтобы приложение java запускалось при загрузке windows и каждые 2 часа обращалась к бд и выводило сообщение. Вопрос такой: как сделать или батник или, что было бы намного лучше, инсталяшку, чтобы она записывала там в реестр или я не знаю куда инф, чтобы все это дело запускалось и весело в трее. И отдельно, как настроить postgresql, чтобы она тоже запускалась автоматически. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для автозагрузки приложения после старта Windows надо прописать путь в реестре в один из этих ключей

> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

В HKLM пишут администраторы, а в HKCU - пользователи. Для служб есть подобный набор ключей.

Обращение через каждые два часа делается средствами самого языка (в данном случае Java).

Значок в трее и все, с ним связанное, в Win API делается с помощью [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx).

База данных должна запускаться после перезагрузки системы сама при установке по умолчанию. Если это не так, то также надо прописать путь к скрипту автозапуска в реестре. Подробнее здесь: [Starting the Database Server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/postmaster-start.html) (хотя там не про Windows).

Comment: спасибо за ответ! но хотелось бы это дело как-то автоматизировать, т.к предпологается, что пользователей будет много, и на каждой машине не хочется прописывать... как хотябы записать в реестр через батник?

Comment: В реестр батник запишет нужные ключи вызовами regedit.exe. Либо, если будет создан установщик msi, он тоже сможет писать в реестр.

Answer (score 0):

Добавление задания на windows 7 (на ХР по аналогии):

```
schtasks /create /tn TestJava /sc daily /tr "java -cp D:\java\.projects\TestJava\bin TestJava" /ri 2 /f
```

Удаление задания на windows 7 (на ХР по аналогии):

```
schtasks /delete /tn TestJava
```

Параметры планировщика заданий:

```
/create - команда планировщику заданий
/tn - имя задания
/sc - частота выполнения задания
/tr - команда которую надо выполнить
/ri - интервал повторения (у меня интервал стоит 2 минуты вам надо поставить 120 )
/f  - force флаг (для перезаписи задания)
```

команда которую я запускаю:

```
"java -cp D:\java\.projects\TestJava\bin TestJava"
```

где

```
java - jvm
-cp D:\java\.projects\TestJava\bin - задаем classpath (в моем случае это путь к eclipse проэкту + bin)
TestJava - имя класса который выполняется
```

Исходный код тестового класса:

```
public class TestJava
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        File file = new File ( "C:/schedule.txt" ) ;
        if ( !file.exists () )
        {
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile () ;
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "no permission to create file" ) ;
            }
        }
        if ( file.exists () && !file.isFile () )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "file is a directory" ) ;
        }

        update ( file ) ;
    }

    private static void update ( File file )
    {
        try
        {
            final BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( file, true ) ) ;
            w.write ( new SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" ).format ( new Date () ) ) ;
            w.newLine () ;
            w.close () ;
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "no permission to update file" ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

schedule.txt (сгенерированный файл) :

```
2012-02-15 05:55:00
2012-02-15 05:57:00
```